# Wordpress ajax->php request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Sorry if there is theme like this, but i didn't find solution for my problem. So let's go... =)(I'm starting to learn php).

This is calendar of events and it will be widget for WP. It need to work onclick event. All code written in one file(this is plugin). In widget(in right sidebar) i write phpcode(for testing) where i call this functions. 
http://herytire.esy.es/calendar
You can push '2' or '5' dates, there is data in mysql for these dates.
All works fine, but i never work with php in wordpress, and have problems with this code.

The problem is:

When i use this code in simple html page, you can see it at link above, all works fine, I get results for day that I click, BUT in wp, `alert(for error)`, returns `undefined`. Two days I'm trying to fix this problem, but nothing. I hope somebody can help me please..!

**admin-ajax.php is done for view side of wp!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // ajaxurl in header.php
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>

/*
Plugin Name: Release Dates
Description: Small calendar for serials release dates.
Author: J_J
Version: 1.0
*/

function draw_calendar($month, $year) // creating calendar
{
  $month = date('m');
  $year = date('y');
  $calendar = '<table class="calendar">';
  $headings = array('S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S');
  $calendar .= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">', $headings).'</td></tr>';
  $running_day = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
  $days_in_month = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
  $days_in_this_week = 1;
  $day_counter = 0;
  $dates_array = array();
  $calendar .= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
  for ($x = 0; $x < $running_day; ++$x) {
      $calendar .= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
      ++$days_in_this_week;
  }
  for ($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; ++$list_day) {
      $calendar .= '<td class="calendar-day"><div class="day-number"><a style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="relDaySerial('.$list_day.');">'.$list_day.'</a></div></td>';
      if ($running_day == 6) {
          $calendar .= '</tr>';
          if (($day_counter + 1) != $days_in_month) {
              $calendar .= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
          }
          $running_day = -1;
          $days_in_this_week = 0;
      }
      ++$days_in_this_week;
      ++$running_day;
      ++$day_counter;
  }
  if ($days_in_this_week < 8) {
      for ($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); ++$x) {
          $calendar .= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
      }
  }
  $calendar .= '</tr>'.'</table>';
  return $calendar; }

function get_serials($day) { // here i catch relDaySerial:id
 if ($_POST['relDaySerial'] === null) {
    $day = date('d');
} else {
    $day = $_POST['relDaySerial'];
}

global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tvt_calendar WHERE day=$day");
foreach ($result as $value) {
    echo "
  <table id='cal-data'>
    <tr>
      <td class='calendar-day-head'>TV Show</td>
      <td class='calendar-day-head'>S</td>
      <td class='calendar-day-head'>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='cal-content'>
      <td><a href='#'>".$value->title.'</a></td>
      <td>'.$value->season.'</td>
      <td>'.$value->series.'</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    ';
}}
function my_action_javascript() {
  ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function relDaySerial(id) {
jQuery.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:ajaxurl,
  data:{relDaySerial:id},
success:function(data) {
  if(relDaySerial.type == "success") {
     jQuery('#cal-bottom').html(data)
  }
  else {
     alert()
   }
}});}
</script>
<?php}
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action_javascript', 'my_action_javascript');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_javascript', 'my_action_javascript');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `alert()` requires a parameter.
Try with this:

`alert('An error has occurred.');`

Comment: I need to return relDaySerial data(number of day), i don't need error message 'An error has occurred')))

Comment: Well dude. Since someone has edited your question I understand now what you mean.
You said it's not finished but I was gonna cap and test your code and yours seems to be only a part of a whole like a `<?php` is missing and `ajaxurl` is not defined? Because that's where the data will be sent to for the id. Also, `add_action()` where is it built? Better work on it more or please make a more structured explanation with comments in code. No offence, but that's the most reason why people avoid interfering here when a bunch of code is not commented.